# Specify textcolor in newcommand

Tags: beamer, teaching

I am preparing lecture slides. Need to hide some comments from the students. How can I change the color of the text in `\hideit`?

```
\newcommand\hideit[1]{%
\only<0| handout:1>{\mbox{}}%
\invisible<0| handout:1>{#1}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Can you provide `MWE` of what you tried as of now.?

Comment: What do you want exactly? To have the text invisible to everybody? Or to have the text visible on your computer screen, but not on what is displayed for students?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
\newcommand\hideit[1]{%
\only<0| handout:1>{\mbox{}}%
\invisible<0| handout:1>{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
```

?

Comment: This works. Thanks!